# Regex match character and non-ascii characters

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a script to clean up a file line-by-line with non-ascii characters, but I am having trouble with a regex pattern. I need a regex pattern that matches any line that starts with an asterisk, may have an equals, and will contain non-ascii characters and spaces. I know how to match a non-ascii character, but not in the same set as other positively defined characters.

Here is a sample line that I need to match:

```
* = Ìÿð ÿð
```

Here is the pattern I have so far:

```
/\*[^[:ascii:]]+[\r\n]/
```

This will match lines that start with asterisk and containing non-ascii characters, but not if the line has spaces or equals in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
^\*\s*=?\s*[[:^ascii:]\s]+[\r\n]*$
```

This matches the start-of-line `^`, then it matches zero or more spaces `\s*` followed by an optional equal sign `=?` then zero or more white spaces `\s*`.

Now a nice piece of expression matches one or more characters which are a combination of non-ascii and white spaces `[[:^ascii:]\s]+`, check [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) to see the syntax for character classes.

Finally the expression matches a combination of carriage returns and newlines which may end the line.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qR5bF3)

Comment: @Broxzier OK thank you, although I find sometimes that explaining the pattern by writing it helps a lot.

Comment: Careful, if you check the control paths you see that this matches just an asterisk as well.

Comment: @sln Thank you for you observation. My expression after its last edit only matches if there is at least one non-ascii or white space character.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this - (edit: changed after reread )

```
 # ^\*(?=.*[^\0-\177])

 ^ 
 \*
 (?= .* [^\0-\177] )
```